# Unexpected token < error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a problem with my project. This is my idea:

- Bypass CORS to another domain with JSONP: I do it !
- Converted XML to JSONP: Because data in domain is XML.
- Do something with this data as a XML file.

The problem is: it always return: `Unexpected token <`. I know it can't read XML as JSONP DataType. But in my opinion, JS can converted XML to JSONP, if it's right. Please suggest me how to use it.

This is my code:

```
function test(){
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    processData: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: true,  
    url: "http://huysoi.com/den.xml",
    //converters: {"xml": jQuery.parseXML},
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin',
    success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('in');
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});

<input type="button" onclick="return test();" >
```

[image]

Comment: `jsonp: 'jsonp', `   ????

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace at the end!

Comment: I'd say you'll need *at least* recursive parsing and rendering of XML/JSON.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Please show me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. You can't send ajax request for xml with jsonp.
I had the same problem and finally I used post messaging with iframe for solving the cross domain problem

see
https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage

Comment: Can you share with me?
Thank you so much. I'm so headache with this problem >.<

Comment: Sure. I used the https://github.com/ofirdagan/cross-domain-local-storage . You need to create iframe and then add post messaging for passing xml with local storage

Comment: Does it work with basic protected domain ???